# (@syncfusion/ej2-angular-schedule) ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, angular, syncfusion, angular-ivy

I was trying using schedule feature from **@syncfusion/ej2-angular-schedule** npm library. I followed the steps mentioned in the official site (**https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/schedule/getting-started/**). After successfully downloading all the dependencies, when I compiled my angular app, the Ivy compiler started throwing many errors for the existing node modules (got updated after adding syncfusion library). Although, my angular source code got compiled successfully. When I ran my app, it started throwing another error in console "**Maximum call stack size exceeded**".
[image]
[image]

**UPDATE**

I created a fresh project from latest Angular cli  (Angular CLI: 10.0.8) and followed the steps mentioned in the document. Now, my new latest angular project has only code related to get the schedule view rendered. Still I am receiving "Maximum call stack size exceeded error". I guess the library is not stable for Angular.

Comment: Look for any import that could cause circular dependencies. Something, you don't have to use the dependencies, it can only be imported, and still cause a circular dependencies. You could also check what module you import in your app.module. This is a very hard problem to debug, it can takes minutes like it can takes days. There is no magic tools, you just have to get your hands into it and start looking.

Comment: I've had a similar issue when accidentally importing a module into itself. Check what your modules are importing.

Comment: I have updated the post. I am still getting "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error with fresh new project.

Answer (score 1):

moving providers :

```
providers: [DayService, WeekService, WorkWeekService, MonthService, AgendaService],
```

from module to component seems to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

We have validated the reported "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" problem at our side by preparing a sample based on our getting started document in Angular 10 with latest version of the Syncfusion package. But we did not face the mentioned issue. The sample was compiled and working fine. Please find the below sample and our angular environment for your reference.

Sample: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/Schedule-ng10118002288

[Angular environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hn3l4.png)

Kindly try the above sample and if you still face the mentioned issue, could you please share the below details which will be helpful for us to validate further the above issue.
Share the complete schedule rendering code.
Share the video demo with the issue replication Or
Replicate your problem in the above sample Or
Share the issue replication sample(If possible) for serve you better.